# Is it safe to set an anti-CSRF token on $http for Ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, csrf

It seems creating and handling anti-CSRF tokens for Ajax calls in an Angular application is non-trivial and some are getting around the problem by applying a single token to every Ajax call. For example [here](http://blog.novanet.no/anti-forgery-tokens-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs/).

The solution is quite neat. We just generate the token on the server and send it along with the first loaded page after sign-in. Then we ensure it goes out with all future requests like this:

`$http.defaults.headers.common['RequestVerificationToken'] = 'token should go here';`

But I am concerned this may simplify the job of an attacker. They need only get hold of $http in order to make any valid request. Is this the case? Is this method safe? Is there a 'best practice' regarding Ajax requests and CSRF?

Comment: that's why your app should communicate with the server through https.If you're not using https,dont bother trying to secure anything at first place,it will not be.As for user generated content,well it's up to you to sanitize whatever content the user generate,to avoid XSS.But angular is pretty tough on displaying html content.Unless you append user generated html directly to the dom through jqlite you shoud be fine.

Comment: Why not cookies (which Angular takes care of automatically) ?

Answer (score 1):

Angular automatically does this for you.

Read **Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection** section. 
[DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection)

I also suggest you read up CSRF, and what it is, if malicious script is already in your page it does not need to do cross-site requests to pose as the victim.